# Php return multiple array

Tags: php

I would like to return multiple arrays and then separate them.

```
function cal(){
    $st1=array('1','2'); 
    $st2=array('1','2');
    return $st1."-".$st2;
}
```

call it

```
$mainstring=explode("-",cal())
print_r($mainstring[0]);
print_r($mainstring[1]);
```

I want to get original array of $st1 and $st2.

Please help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply change your function `cal()` to

```
function cal(){
    $st1=array('1','2'); 
    $st2=array('1','2');
    return array($st1,$st2);
}
```

And then do

```
$mainstring=cal();
print_r($mainstring[0]);
print_r($mainstring[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to preserve the array names you could use [list()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php);

```
function cal(){
    $st1=array('1','2'); 
    $st2=array('1','2');
    return array($st1,$st2);
}

list($st1,$st2)=cal();
print_r($st1);
print_r($st2);
```